# Проблема с AutoMapper в ASP.NET MVC. Ошибка System.TypeLoadException: "Отсутствует реализация метода "GetEnumerator"

Tags: asp.net, oracle, repository, automapper

С помощью automapper пытался делать маппинг модели БД на модель Dto

```
internal class DepartamentStructService : IDepartamentStructService
{
    private IUnitOfWork Database { get; set; }

    private IAutoMapper AutoMapper { get; set; }

    public DepartamentStructService(IUnitOfWork database, IAutoMapper autoMapper)
    {
        Database = database;
        AutoMapper = autoMapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<DepartamentStructDto> GetDepartamentStructAll() => AutoMapper.Projection<IEnumerable<DEPARTMENTSTRUCT>, IEnumerable<DepartamentStructDto>>(Database.DepartamentsStruct.GetAll());

    public void Dispose() => Database.Dispose();
}
```

И получаю вот такую ошибку System.TypeLoadException: "Отсутствует реализация метода "GetEnumerator", уже все перепробывал не знаю что делать, подскажите!
За интерфейсом IAutoMapper стоит класс

```
internal class AutoMapperCollection : IAutoMapper
{
    public TDestination Projection<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source) 
        where TSource : class
        where TDestination : class
    {
        var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()).CreateMapper();
        return mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что у вас возвращает следующий код: Database.DepartamentsStruct.GetAll()

Comment: @Vadim Bondaruk, во это: IEnumerable<DEPARTMENTSTRUCT>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
public IEnumerable<TDestination> Projection<TSource, TDestination>(IEnumerable<TSource> source) 
    where TSource : class
    where TDestination : class
{
    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()).CreateMapper();
    return source.Select(x => mapper.Map<TDestination>(x));
}
```

И еще нужно 100% соответствие между моделю Db и Dto по полям!