# Automapper. Маппинг внутри CreateMap

Tags: c#, automapper

У меня есть примерно такой код:

```
CreateMap<Entity, EntityResponse>(); // #1

CreateMap<Source<Entity>, Dest<EntityResponse>>()
    .ConvertUsing(source =>
    {
        // здесь мне нужно вызвать маппинг описанный в строке 1#
        EntityResponse resp = <mapping>; 
        int someInt = source.SomeInt;
        string someStr = source.SomeString;
        return new Dest(resp, someInt, someString);
    });
```

Класс `Dest` имеет такой конструктор:

```
Dest(EntityResponse item, int someInt, string someStr)
```

Как мне вызвать маппинг из `Entity` в `EntityResponse`? Заранее спасибо

Comment: а зачем Вы в CreateMap<Source<Entity>, Dest<EntityResponse>>() указываете Source<> и Dest<> что это будет

Comment: посмотрите здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/832091/261244

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На ходу можно так

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source<Entity>, Dest<EntityResponse>>().
    ConstructUsing((source,context) =>
{
    EntityResponse resp = context.Mapper.Map<EntityResponse>(source.Entity);
    int someInt = source.SomeInt;
    string someStr = source.SomeString;
    return new Dest(resp, someInt, someString);
}).ForAllMembers(s => s.Ignore());
```