# AspNetCore2.1. Не работает mapping через Automapper для объекта IdentityUser (ApplicationUser->ApplicationUserDto)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

Нужно предоставить WebApi доступ к `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` `(AspNetCore.Identity)`.
Для этого нужно сделать mapping `ApplicationUser` в `ApplicationUserDto`.
Возникает исключение

```
Exception = "\nUnmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.\nAdd a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type\nFor no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of...
```

Настройка AutoMapper:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class ApplicationUserDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Вызов маппера:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    var users = _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.Company).ToList();
    try
    {
        var usersDto = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUserDto>(users); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e); //!!!! ЛОВЛЮ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
    }

    await Task.CompletedTask;
    return new JsonResult(usersDto);
}
```

Comment: предлагаю Вам посмотреть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/832091/261244

Comment: Спасибо, а почему такие сложности?

Comment: даже не скажу :)

Comment: ОК, спасибо еще раз попробую)

Comment: должно работать)